# Spring Boot Localization issue - Accept-Language header

Tags: java, spring, rest, localization, spring-boot

We are using Spring Boot for the application. In ApplicationConfig.java I have the below code

```
 @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new SmartLocaleResolver();
    }
```

and the SmartLocaleResolver.java is below

```
public class SmartLocaleResolver extends SessionLocaleResolver {

    @Override
    public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String acceptLanguage = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        if (acceptLanguage.contains(",")) {
            String[] aheader = acceptLanguage.split(",[ ]*");    
            for (String locale : aheader) {    
                if (ApplicationConstants.LOCALE.contains(locale)) {
                    locale.trim();
                    return Locale.forLanguageTag(locale);
                }
            }
        } else if (!acceptLanguage.contains(",") && !acceptLanguage.isEmpty()) {
            if (ApplicationConstants.LOCALE.contains(acceptLanguage)) {
                return Locale.forLanguageTag(acceptLanguage);
            }
        }
        return request.getLocale();
    }
}
```

and I have in my constants class the below to compare the value from header Accept-Language.

public static final List LOCALE                          = Collections
            .unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("en", "es"));

I know in actual scenario the header will be like
Accept-Language : fr,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.6 but for testing purpose i'm passing it as below.

Accept-language : fr,es,en

The code is not complete yet, but i'm just testing from postman to see if the code picks up "es" as the locale and gives me the localized result.

I don't have messages_fr.properties file but I have messages_es.properties so I expect if the application sets the locale from the below code, it would pick Locale as 'es' and give the values I want in Spanish. What changes I need to make here for the code to work?

Comment: Why not call `request.getLocale()` directly?

Comment: If i just call request.getLocale() directly how does it verify that we don't support 'fr'  in my project ? I do not have messages_fr.properies in my project. So it needs to ignore fr and would need to set Locale as 'es' because we support 'es' and have messages_es.properties. Can it automatically do that without I writing any logic for that?

Comment: @Arun I know this is old and you probably solved it, but I am just wondering: couldn't you just have named `messages_es.properties` `messages.properties` instead and if e.g. `request.getLocale()` returns an unsupported language, it just falls back to whatever default language (`messages.properties` without any suffix) you have provided?

Comment: @Igor I had many .properties files for different languages and the API needs to return the correct string values based on the header value. Don't think having one file messages.properties for different languages works as it needs to pick different values based on the header value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution is:

```
public class SmartLocaleResolver extends AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
```

instead of

```
public class SmartLocaleResolver extends SessionLocaleResolver
```

Below is the updated code:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.bbtransact.tss.api.commons.http.HttpConstants;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver;

public class SmartLocaleResolver extends AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver {
  @Override
  public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
     if (StringUtils.isBlank(request.getHeader("Accept-Language"))) {
         return Locale.getDefault();
       }
     List<Locale.LanguageRange> list = Locale.LanguageRange.parse(request.getHeader("Accept-Language"));
     Locale locale = Locale.lookup(list, ApplicationConstants.LOCALES);
      return locale;
     }
}
```

and in my constants class I have:

```
List<Locale> LOCALES = Arrays.asList(new Locale("en"),
                                         new Locale("es"),
                                         new Locale("fr"),
                                         new Locale("es", "MX"),
                                         new Locale("zh"),
                                         new Locale("ja"));
```