# Accept-Language header handling in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring MVC supports `org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` for locale resolution in `ResourceBundleMessageSource`.

Problem with this is, it only considers the primary locale in the accept-language header. However accept-language as per HTTP specs supports multiple languages with preference for each language.

Is there a way in spring MVC to resolve locales based on the preference and available locales in my resource bundle?

For instance if I have following message resources

```
Message.properties
Messages_en_US.properties
Messages_ko_KR.properties
```

if the accept header is something like below

```
Accept-Language: ko, ko-kr;q=0.8, en;q=0.7
```

AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver only resolves `ko`, sine I do not have messages for this locale ResourceBundleMessageSource driectly fetches the messages from default locale Meassages.properties.

I would like to pickup messages from ko_KR since this is second preference instead of directly jumping to default.

I can write some code to do this using the ServletRequest.getLocales() enumeration which gives me locales in the preferred order. However ResourceBundle does not have a API method which returns all the locales for which I have messages, so I have to write some hack code to prepare this list. I just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Check this out, https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/.

Comment: I know how to use resourcebundlemessagesource, what I am looking for is different please read the problem statement one more time

Comment: Why would anyone down vote this, this is a genuine problem.

Comment: Google... Check this, may be a workaround.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655104/spring-boot-localization-issue-accept-language-header